# focus next link in ajax result with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use arrow up/down keys to select items in a search result,

the next link won't be focused however, what am I doing wrong?

live at http://jsfiddle.net/JJDfL/1/

```
$('#hitbox').on('keyup','a', function(event) {
    //focus prev/next with arrows, enter and escape
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
      $('#hitbox').slideUp(100);
      $('#searchbox').val('');
      $('#searchbox').focus();
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40) {
      var focused = $(':focus');    
      focused.parent().next().focus();
      alert(focused.parent().next().html()); //returns '<a href="asdf">bb</a>'
    }
  });
```

UPDATE:

works now:

```
 focused.parent().next().find('a').focus();
```

solved the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/JJDfL/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

There are a couple of problems, but ive edited your fiddle and it should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/JJDfL/6/

Problem 1:
You are not selecting the right element when you press down (once you have selected the first link). Fix that by:

```
$(this).parent().next().find("a").focus();
```

Notice the .find("a") to select the <a> element inside the <p> element, you could use the children("a") method aswell.

Problem 2:
You are not stopping the propagation of the event, this makes the event trigger on the recently focused item aswell, fix that by:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Also, your query variable seems to be unnecessary if you return when the function is done.

Comment: Thanks, but in Chrome and ff the 40 triggers (alert shown). Try entering "asdf" in the searchbox at the fiddle, the #hitbox will be populated by fake-ajax.

Comment: You are right, i have edited the answer with additional information.